# Inconsistent redirection to root page(Search page)

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to troubleshoot an existing .Net application which I did not code. The application runs on a split config windows server 2016 server(DB is on another server) running .NET version 4.7.2. The application was developed on .Net 4.6.2. There are certain pages in the application which get rerouted to the landing page(a search page) inconsistently. Sometimes it routes to the correct page and sometimes it routes back to the search page. The logs show that the target URL gets generated sometimes and is empty the other times. I am trying to access the same page every time and it is not dynamic. I am confused on how to  troubleshoot this. Any inputs are appreciated.

LOGS:

{REST.aspx.cs} ProcessRequest() redirect=False to=>~/Profile/Display.aspx?subject=107310&predicate=345&object=&tab=timeline&file=&viewas=HTML&ContentType=text/html&StatusCode=200&SessionID=5F1CA70C-BCB1-464C-8E90-FFCA5736CEA5 2:18:42 PM

Above is the line logged for accessing a page which opened up the tab successfully.

{REST.aspx.cs} ProcessRequest() redirect=False to=> 2:10:55 PM

Above is the line logged for accessing the same page,a couple of seconds later which routed back to the landing page instead.

Comment: Can you share the code? This will make it easier for us to help you

Comment: Please use proper formatting for your question. It will help a lot.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask